# What is the extract-min run-time and why?

Tags: data-structures, heap, extract

why does it take O(lg n) for extract-min in a heap?

Comment: Explained, let me know if you got it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See there: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap#Extract

In a few words, you do three steps:

- First, replace the root of the heap with the last element on the last level. It's done for O(1).
- Second, compare new root with it's children (still O(1)). If everything is ok, you're done!
- Now it's tricky. If new root is bigger (we consider you have a minimum on the top) than one of it's children, swap them! Now you (probably) have the same trouble in the subtree of the child. Go ahead and repeat steps 2 and 3 inside of the subtree! You will **not** have to repeat this more times than the count of levels in the tree, since each time you go one level down. Balanced binary tree has O(lg N) levels in it. Note: if your root is bigger than both of it's children, swap with the lesser one (you want to bring it up).

Comment: You can understand that the height (amount of levels) in the binary tree is O(lg N) this way: on the first level of tree you have 1 element, on the second level you have 2, on third -- 4, then 8, 16 and so on, to keep 31 elements inside of your tree you need 5 layers, to keep 63 you need 6, to keep 127 you need 7. It's observable =)